# Ubuntu uninstall problem

Tags: 12.10, wubi

I installed my Ubuntu 12.10 using wubi.exe. My laptop crashed and I decided to re-install my Windows. Now, I cannot uninstall Wbuntu 12.10 using the control panel in Windows. I have already deleted the folders of Ubuntu 12.10 from my local disk from where its data is placed.

I thought that by using this deletion method, Ubuntu will not show whenever I reboot, but it is still there.

Can you please give advise on how I will handle this uninstall problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is deleted, only the entry is there. use bcdedit if you are on vista, win7 to delete the entry

on xp, you need to edit c:\boot.ini to remove the line containing ububntu line.

caution : for both cases don't delete windows related line/ entry